# Create n files with random filenames in batch script (Windows) - my script creates only one file

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file

I need to write a batch script, in which I would like to take an argument (lets call it `n`), and create `n` empty files, with random filenames. However, my approach seems not to work, since, it does not create `n` files, but just one:

```
@echo off

set arg=%1

FOR /L %%i IN (1, 1, %arg%) DO (
  set FILENAME=file%RANDOM%.txt
  copy /b NUL %FILENAME%
)

pause
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) of the variables in the loop, so they become expanded at execution time rather than at parse time:

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set arg=%1

FOR /L %%i IN (1, 1, %arg%) DO (
  set FILENAME=file!RANDOM!.txt
  copy /b NUL !FILENAME!
)

pause
```

Comment: Although this approach will be sufficient in many situations, be aware that `!RANDOM!` in the `FOR /L` loop may return duplicate numbers; you might be interested in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34406594) concerning generation of random numbers without duplicates...

Answer (score 0):

This approach ensures that no collisions occur, that is, the generated random numbers are unique:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set "ARG=%~1"
set /A ARG+=0

if %ARG% LSS 1472 (goto :FEW) else (goto :MANY)


:MANY
for /L %%I in (0,1,32767) do (
    set "RND_!RANDOM!=%%I"
)
set /A COUNT=0
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%J in ('set RND_') do (
    set /A COUNT+=1
    if !COUNT! GTR %ARG% goto :SKIP
    ECHO copy /B nul "file%%J.txt"
)
:SKIP
goto :END


:FEW
set /A COUNT=0
:LOOP
if %COUNT% GEQ %ARG% goto :CONT
set /A COUNT+=1
set "RND_%COUNT%=%RANDOM%"
set /A TEST=COUNT-1
for /L %%I in (1,1,%TEST%) do (
    if !RND_%%I! EQU !RND_%COUNT%! (
        set /A COUNT-=1
    )
)
goto :LOOP
:CONT
for /L %%J in (1,1,%COUNT%) do (
    ECHO copy /B nul "FILE!RND_%%J!.txt"
)
goto :END


:END
endlocal
exit /B
```

Call the above script with the number of random files as a command line argument.

The script contains two routines for generating the random numbers:

- `:FEW`: The random numbers are collected in an array-style variable `RND_#` where `#` represents the index from `1` up to the number of items to be generated. Every newly generated number is compared against all previous ones and whenever a match is found, generation is repeated, until the total amount is reached. Finally the empty random files are generated.
- `:MANY`: Unique random numbers are generated with an approach similar to the one of this post: [How to generate a list of random numbers without duplicates in pure batch scripting?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34426294)

Depending on the number of random files to be created, the appropriate routine is selected. The routine `:FEW` is good for only a few random numbers; as soon as the total number increases, the probability of receiving duplicates and hence the said repetition of the random number generation makes it quite inefficient.
The routine `:MANY` is slow for a few random numbers because there is always a random sequence of `32768` items generated; as soon as the total amount increases, this method is the better choice for the sake of overall performance.
The used limit number `1472` below which the `:FEW` routine is chosen is just an arbitrary value here.

There are upper-case `ECHO` commands prefixed at the `copy` commands for testing. Whenever you want to actually create any files, simply remove them.